# Can I save my trained model in Accord.NET

Tags: c#, machine-learning, accord.net

I created a trained model Using the library Accord.NET. I would like to keep the pre-trained model in a file (not in the RAM memory), and later to use that model in my desktop application in C#,  how this is possible?

Comment: I wonder why is it marked duplicate?

Comment: In the duplicate question I founded the class Accord.IO with that class now is possible save the pre-trained model. But the library must be updated